# Ignore/Flatten xml element in python3

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml.etree

My xml element looks like this:

```
<para>Lorem ipsum (R<inf>0</inf>) dolor sit amnet</para>
```

Trying to get the entire text with

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.fromstring('<para>Lorem ipsum (R<inf>0</inf>) dolor sit amnet</para>')
xml.text
```

results in `'Lorem ipsum (R'`. Hence, the part after `<inf>` is completely ignored.  How can I make the xml parser ignore/delete this element?

Comment: Does `''.join(your_xml.itertext())` work in your use case?

Comment: It does! Yes, great solution

Comment: Do you mind upgrading your comment to a question? Then I'll accept it to mark the question as solved.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer if you want... I have a feeling it's probably been asked before and I have a gut feeling there's actually a slightly better solution than this one - but I'm probably thinking of what one can do with `lxml` instead of Python's builtin `xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is plain and simple: Join the elements returned from `.itertext()`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.fromstring('<para>Lorem ipsum (R<inf>0</inf>) dolor sit amnet</para>')
''.join(xml.itertext())
```

Credits go out to Jon Clements.